# Need help how to use with event.stopPropagation() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

Since I am new to jQuery, I want to use event.stopPropagation() in my script.

I have used it in following manner:

```
this.$el.find(".activity_row").on("click", this.on_row_click, function (event){
                event.stopPropagation()
            });
```

I have another on click events under "**activity_row**". for that i want to aply event.stopPropagation(), But it's not working!

Please guide me how to use this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this.$el.find(".activity_row").on("click", this.on_row_click, function (event){
               if (event.preventDefault)
                  event.preventDefault();
               if (event.stopPropagation)
                  event.stopPropagation();


            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [demo JsFiddel for your question here](http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/jzw415o8/)

```js
$('.btn1').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('It is first btn');
});
$('.btn1').click(function(){
    alert('It is first btn');
});

$('.btn2').click(function(){
    alert('It is second btn');
});

$('.btn-container').click(function(){
    alert('It is btn container');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn1">Button</button>
    <button class="btn2">Button</button>
</div>
```

In codes above, you can find that the function `event.stopPropagation()` just prevent the event spread to outer DOM, so when you click the `btn1`, the event in `.btn-container` won't be triggered.

But for the `.btn1`, if you rigister two event handlers like my code above, when you click the `.btn1`, all of event handlers in it will be triggered.